# Is it possible to add external arguments to form partial field names?

Tags: r

I have two fields:

```
FirstVisit
SecondVisit
```

I am building a function to pull data from either field depending on user input (heavily reduced yet relevant version of function):

```
pullData(visit){
    # Do something
}
```

What I am looking to do is for the function to take the user's input and use it to form part of the call to the data frame field.

For example, when the user runs:

```
pullData(First)
```

The function will run like this:

```
print(df$FirstVisit)
```

Conversely, when the user runs:

```
pullData(Second)
```

The function will run:

```
print(df$SecondVisit)
```

My function is considerably more complex than this, but this basic example relates to just the specific aspect of it that I am trying to work out.

So far I have tried something like:

```
print(paste0(df["df$", visit, "Visit", ])
# The intention is to result in df$FirstVisit or df$SecondVisit depending on the input
```

And this:

```
print(paste0(df[df$", visit, "Visit, ])
# Again, intended result should be df$FirstVisit or df$SecondVisit, depending on the input
```

among other alternatives (some with `paste()`), yet nothing has worked so far.

I suspect that it is possible and feel that I am close.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `print(df[[paste0(visit, "Visit")]])` should work.

Comment: Do you really want to run the function like `pullData(First)` or do you mean `pullData("First")`

Comment: @Jonas Well the argument will be passed into the field name within the data frame, so it wouldn't necessarily have to be a string, thus `pullData(First)` or `pullData(Second)` should work fine.  I'm happy with either approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run the function like `pullData(First)`, you need to use metaprogramming (to get the name of the argument instead of the arguements value) like

```
pullData <- function(...) {
  arg <- rlang::ensyms(...)
  if(length(arg)!=1) stop("invalid argument in pullData")
  dataName <- paste0(as.character(arg[[1]]),"Visit")
  print(df[[dataName]])
}
```

If you can manage to call the function with a character-argument like `pullData("First")`, you can simply do:

```
pullData <- function(choice = "First") {
  dataName <- paste0(choice,"Visit")
  print(df[[dataName]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you're going for, but here's a possible solution:

```
pullData <- function(visit){

  visit <- rlang::quo_text(enquo(visit))
  visit <- tolower(visit)
  
  
  if (visit %in% c("first", "firstvisit")){
    data <- df$FirstVisit
  }

  if (visit %in% c("second", "secondvisit")){
    data <- df$SecondVisit
  }
data
}
```

Using this sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(FirstVisit = c("first value"),
                 SecondVisit = c("second value"))
```

Gets us:

```
> pullData(first)
[1] "first value"

> pullData(second)
[1] "second value"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, R allows for *partial matching* when subsetting with character indices; see `help("$")`.

```
df <- data.frame(FirstVisit = 11:12, SecondVisit = 21:22)
```

For interactive use:

```
df$F
```

> ```
> [1] 11 12
> ```

```
df$S
```

> ```
> [1] 21 22
> ```

For programming on computed indices, the `[[` operator has to be used, e.g.,

```
df[["F", exact = FALSE]]
```

> ```
> [1] 11 12
> ```

This can be wrapped in a function call:

```
pullData <- function(x) df[[x, exact = FALSE]]
```

Thus,

```
pullData("F")
pullData("Fi")
pullData("First")
pullData("FirstVisit")
```

return all

> ```
> [1] 11 12
> ```

while

```
pullData("S")
pullData("Second")
```

return

> ```
> [1] 21 22
> ```

But watchout when dealing with user supplied input as typos might lead to unexpected results:

```
pullData("f")
pullData("first")
pullData("Frist")
```

> ```
> NULL
> ```